# Pretty Printing a tree data structure in Ruby

Tags: ruby, expression-trees, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working on a building a compiler and within that I generate a tree that represents the source program that is passed in. I want to display this is a tree like fashion so I can display the structure of the program to anyone interested.

Right now I just have the tree printing on a single line like this:

```
ProgramNode -> 'Math' BlockNode -> DeclarationNode -> ConstantDeclarationNode -> const ConstantListNode -> [m := 7, ConstantANode -> [n := StringLiteralNode -> ""TEST"" ]] ;
```

What I would like is something like this:

```
   ProgramNode 
    /     \
'Math' BlockNode
           |
    DeclarationNode
           |
    ConstantDeclarationNode ------------------------------
        /      \                                         |
     const ConstantListNode                              |
             /  |  \      \                              |
             m  :=  7    ConstantANode                   |
                            /  |    \                    |
                           n   :=  StringLiteralNode     |
                                      /    |   \         |
                                      "   TEST  "        ;
```

I haven't really worked with trees in Ruby, how are they usually represented?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: +1 for the pretty ascii tree :)

Comment: Do you just want the trees generated in ascii?

Comment: Print the tree *sideways*, root node first, with childen indented.  See LISP S-expressions for the canonical ways to represent/print trees.  Done right this will take you 1-2 hours.

Comment: @Sean It doesn't necessarily need to be ascii, I just did that as a simple example

Comment: Here's an example of a tree prettyprinted "sideways": http://stackoverflow.com/a/10749970/120163

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of pretty printing requires quite a bit of math. Besides, it's unclear what should happen if the tree grows too wide for the console window. I don't know of any existing libraries that'll do this. I personally use [`awesome_print`](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print).

```
tree = {'ConstantDeclarationNode' => ['const',
                                      'ConstantListNode' => ['m', ':=', '7']]}

require 'awesome_print'

ap tree
# >> {
# >>     "ConstantDeclarationNode" => [
# >>         [0] "const",
# >>         [1] {
# >>             "ConstantListNode" => [
# >>                 [0] "m",
# >>                 [1] ":=",
# >>                 [2] "7"
# >>             ]
# >>         }
# >>     ]
# >> }
```

It has tons of options, check it out!

Comment: [How does `git` do it?](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)

Comment: Thank you, I have never heard of this but it looks really promising.

Comment: Any ideas as to how I could go about passing this data between classes? Each of the nodes in the above tree represents a class in my compiler, should I just return an array from each of those nodes and gather them into a hash somehow?

Answer (score 3):

You need to check out the [Graph](http://rubygems.org/gems/graph) gem. It is amazing and remarkably simple to work with. You can choose the direction of your tree and the shape of the nodes, as well as colors and so much more. I first found out about it at Rubyconf last year and was blown away.

It is as simple as:

```
digraph do
  edge "Programnode", "Blocknode"
  edge "Programnode", "Math"
  edge "Blocknode", "DeclarationNode"
end
```

Obviously you would want to programmatically enter the edges :)

Here is a [link to a pdf](https://github.com/kushali/RubyConf2011_GraphTalk) of the talk which will give more information on it:

There is also a video of the talk on [Confreaks](http://www.confreaks.com/videos/617-cascadiaruby2011-powerful-but-easy-data-visualization-with-the-graph-gem) if you are interested.

Cheers,
Sean

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely look into this