# Parser for reading Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I would like to play around with generating code statistics or simple visualisations from Objective-C classes.  What tools are available which can read obj-c and give semantic information such as "class A extends class B" or "C is a property of class B" ?

- Compiler? (clang)
- Debugger? (lldb / gdb)
- Regex?

Just looking for guidance on what the usual approach to this sort of task is.

EDIT: I should make it clear that I am not trying to do much more than work out simple class relationships at the moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote a [sample project](https://bitbucket.org/iamleeg/objectivebrowser) that uses the clang front-end library to parse Objective-C source, finding out what methods are defined for which classes. It would be simple to adapt this to the need you describe:

- you get a callback on every *declaration*. Look for identities declared with the `CXIdxEntity_ObjCClass` kind, as these are Objective-C classes.
- call `clang_index_getObjCInterfaceDeclInfo()` on the declaration to get the class-specific information about this declaration.
- the `.superinfo` member of this structure tells you what the superclass is!

Comment: Been looking through your source, this is exactly what I needed, thanks.  It's a shame there aren't many human-readable tutorials around libclang but this will go a long way towards helping!

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to work out class relationships, I think a custom regex-based parser would do. If you need something more, the regex approach would soon be doomed to fail and you should consider using Clang to [dump the AST](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/IntroductionToTheClangAST.html), see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649594/how-to-extract-ast-from-objective-c-code).

Answer (score 0):

Good luck with that, there is a lot of work to do, and this is not an easy task
Regexp are very limited, but might work for simple tasks. Probably the quick&dirty option.
Clang can be a good option.
You can also take a look at [CodeWorker](http://codeworker.free.fr)